# Issues in Reorder list - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Reorder list in my page. In IE it is working properly. But in Firefox it is not working properly. I am not able to reorder the last few items. Can any one of you tell what may be the problem?

Comment: and tell us what's a reorder list?

Answer (score 1):

take a look http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx